# The right way of implementing a constructor in C

Tags: c, oop, struct, constructor

I want to create a constructor using C.
What is the cleanest way to achieve this?

My attempt:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct line {
    void (*add_line_ptr)(struct line*, int x, int y);
    int x;
    int y;
};

void add_line(struct line* lptr, int x, int y)
{
    lptr->x = x;
    lptr->y = y;
}


int main()
{
    struct line line1 = {add_line, 0, 0};
    line1.add_line_ptr(&line1, 10, 20);
    printf("%d %d\n", line1.x, line1.y);
}
```

I think that using `line1.add_line(&line1,` is a bit redundant - since it's quite obvious that I want to do the operation on line1.
Is there a way to implement this without passing a pointer to the "object"(struct)? or some other way I didn't think of?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212304/discussion-on-question-by-sergeyrar-the-right-way-of-implementing-a-constructor).

Answer (score 5):

Using function pointers just for the sake of emulating C++-like syntax is just messy with no obvious benefits. You won't have RAII in C no matter what you do, so you need to call constructors/destructors explicitly. If you do so by typing `obj.foo()` or `obj = foo()` has absolutely nothing to do with OO, it's mere coding style.

The main problem here though, is that your code does not have proper OO design, since the struct is completely open and not using private encapsulation. For the same reason as `class line { public: int x; int y; };` is not proper OO either - you don't get OO just because you smash some related variables into an aggregate type, regardless of language.

"Cleanest"/"prettiest" would mean full private encapsulation. In C, that can be achieved with opaque types. I prefer to implement them without hiding pointers behind typedef, so:

**line.h**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct line line; // forward declaration of incomplete type

line* line_construct (int x, int y);
```

**line.c**

```
#include "line.h"

struct line {    // actual definition of the struct, local to line.c
    int x;       // private variable
    int y;       // private variable
};

line* line_construct (int x, int y)
{
  line* obj = malloc (sizeof *obj); 
  if(obj == NULL) { /* error handling here */ } 

  obj->x = x;
  obj->y = y;

  return obj;
}
```

**caller.c**

```
#include "line.h"

int main(void)
{
    line* x = line_construct(10, 20);
}
```

Here `line` is 100% encapsulated and the contents of the struct cannot be accessed by the caller. Since I don't hide pointers behind typedef, the caller must always use `line*` pointers and can never declare an instance of the object directly.

If the constructor is only meant to zero-out the struct members, then it doesn't need to get passed any parameters but can do so internally.

And obviously you need to implement a corresponding destructor with `free` as well.
`line* line_destruct(line* obj) { free(obj); return NULL; }` or so.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't put the initializer into your structure to begin with. Other functions, sure, but not the first one. Something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct line {
    int x;
    int y;
};

void add_line(struct line *lptr, int x, int y)
{
    lptr->x = x;
    lptr->y = y;
}


int main()
{
    struct line line1 = {0, 0};
    add_line(&line1, 10, 20);
    printf("%d %d\n", line1.x, line1.y);
}
```

The reason is that you have to assign the initializer anyway after you allocate your structure, either implicitly or explicitly. In OOP languages you normally name the class you want once, and both the allocator and initializer will run. In C you have to run them separately. Whether you allocate an object on the stack or on the heap, you will have to explicitly name the function you want to call at least once anyway.